# I am making a function to print a dynamically allocated object array based on certain criteria in each element

Tags: c++, visual-c++

While working on an assignment, dealing with making classes, I have gotten a majority of the program written but I have to make two functions that print elements in an array based upon user input But I keep getting errors when trying to pass arguments to the function such as an eo167, I have tried looking but wasn't able to find anything on my problem. I tried just passing the dynamic array to the argument but it keeps saying "argument of type "Employee *" is incompatible with parameter of type "Employee **"

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Employee {
private:
    int ID;
    string name;
    string depName;
    int salary;

public:
    Employee();

    void setID(int newID) { ID = newID; }
    void setName(string newName) { name = newName; }
    void setDepName(string newDepName) { depName = newDepName; }
    void setSalary(int newSalary) { salary = newSalary; }
    int getID() { return ID; }
    string getName() { return name; }
    string getDepName() { return depName; }
    int getSalary() { return salary; }
    void print(Employee arr[], int n) {
        cout << "Employees" << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cout << ID << " " << name << " " << depName << " " << salary << endl;
        }
    }
};

using namespace std;

ifstream inFile;

int main() {
    int employees;
    int id;
    int salar;
    string names;
    string dep;

    // for menu choice later
    int num;

    inFile.open("employees.txt");

    inFile >> employees;
    Employee* eArr = new Employee[employees];

    for(int i = 0; i < employees; i++) {
        inFile >> id >> names >> dep >> salar;

        eArr[i].setID(id);
        eArr[i].setName(names);
        eArr[i].setDepName(dep);
        eArr[i].setSalary(salar);
    }

    inFile.close();

    cout << "1) Print Employees" << endl;
    cout << "2) Print by Department" << endl;
    cout << "3) Print by Salary" << endl;
    cout << "4) Exit" << endl;

    cout << "What would you like to do?";
    cin >> num;

    if(num == 1) {
        eArr->print(eArr, employees);
    }

    if(num == 2) {
        printSalary(eArr, employees);
    }

    if(num == 3) {
        printDepartment(eArr, employees);
    }

    return 0;
}

void printSalary(Employee* arr[], int m) {
    int salar2;
    cout << "Salary?";
    cin >> salar2;
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        if(arr[i]->getSalary >= salar2) {
            cout << arr[i];
        }
    }
}

void printDepartment(Employee* arr[], int z) {
    string department;
    cout << "department?";
    cin >> department;
    for(int i = 0; i >= z; i++) {
        if(arr[i]->getDepName == department) {
            cout << arr[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using `std::vector`?

Comment: He specifically wanted it to be an array built from a text file. Not a vector, that's the only reason.

Comment: the definition of your function printSalary function, actually is void printSalary(Employee**arr, int m); is that what you really want to achieve? and it's same for printDepartment.

Comment: What I want it to achieve is to go through the object array and print out employees that match the user input. They are similar because I figured that the functions would be the similar but it seems I might be confusing something here. When I tried removing the "*" from Employee in the print functions it created different errors saying it needed a pointer type

Comment: What is the type of `eArr`? That's the type that `printSalary` and `printDepartment` should take as a parameter.  (Also, `Employee::print` has an unused first parameter.)

Comment: The type of eArr is a pointer object array or rather I believe it's type should be Employee. When I passed `Employee` to the regular `print function` it didn't come up with any errors but when I put the `if statement` into the others it came up with errors even if I remove the pointer from `Employee`

Comment: Make it `void printSalary(Employee arr[], int m)` (drop the star); same as `print`. And similarly with `printDepartment`. Also, you need to move the definitions of these two functions before `main`, or at least provide forward declarations before `main`.